# What could explain this behavior in UDP multicast via WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, multicast, datagram

Here is the scenario:  I have 5 apps which all share a common DLL which contains P2P networking functionality that I wrote.  One of these apps works perfectly every single time, but the others experience the following problem:

On a multicast broadcast our x86 based tablet can send and receive packets fine, but my x64 computer and ARM tablet can only send packets.  The only difference is that they use different ports.  I thought that must be it, and tried switching the other apps to use the same ports as the working app as a test, but that was a no-go.  Here is the relevant portion of code that handles setting up the broadcasting system.

```
public async Task<bool> Startup() {
    if (P2PNetwork.LocalUser == null || this._listenSocket != null)
        return false;

    ConnectionProfile connection = null;

    //See note 1 below
    bool gotConnection = TryGetValidNetworkConnection(out connection);
    if(!gotConnection)
        return false;

    this._heartbeatTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(DoHeartbeat, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    var socket = new DatagramSocket();
    var stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(LANBroadcasting.MULTICAST_GROUP_ADDRESS, P2PNetwork.NetworkGroup.SendPort);
    this._outStreamWriter = new DataWriter(stream);

    this._listenSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    this._listenSocket.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    await this._listenSocket.BindServiceNameAsync(P2PNetwork.NetworkGroup.ReceivePort, connection.NetworkAdapter);

    this._listenSocket.JoinMulticastGroup(LANBroadcasting.MULTICAST_GROUP_ADDRESS);

    DoHeartbeat(HeartbeatFlags.Ping);

    return true;
}
```

NOTE 1:  These symptoms were happening before for all 5 applications.  At that time I was using the `BindServiceNameAsync` without any arguments.  After extensive research I found a page that suggested that that approach was not good, and that the Windows 8.1 method that takes a connection profile worked more reliably.  I checked the profile multiple times and I get the wireless LAN profile, which is correct for both.

In this case (non-working) the tablet's send port is 50011 and its receive port is 50010.  The multicast address is ff02::fb (I've tried IPv4 as well, no change)  The PC in this case is the reverse of that.  I confirmed that the packets are sending via Wireshark.

[image: Wireshark Output]

I also see this line of output via `netstat -a` on the PC (which is failing to receive)

```
UDP     [::]:50011        *.*
```

Despite all this looking correct, my PC simply does not get the `OnMessageReceived` method called (except for the one app which mysteriously works).  What should I be looking for that can cause this odd behavior?  I tried changing the ports on the working application to see if it would fail but it didn't.  I also tried running the app on a different tablet to see if it was just this PC, but I got the same results on the other tablet.  Could the app be failing to join the multicast group?  How would I know since the method returns `void`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of banging my head against the wall, I finally got the answer.  If you experience this problem, go to your Windows Firewall Settings and check what kind of network you are connected to.  In my case, the Wi-Fi was a Guest / Public network.  Apparently this means that it is considered "Internet" by the Windows Runtime and not "Private Network".  In Package.appxmanifest I had the "Private Network (Client and Server)" options selected, but only "Internet (Client)" (which provides outbound access only) and not "Internet (Client and Server)" on all but the one application that was working for some reason.

On a side note:  this doesn't explain why the one x86 tablet was still able to receive for all apps.  I can only assume this is some kind of driver flaw.

This should really trigger some kind of warning message because this simple setting is way too easy to overlook.